# RPSystemBroadcaster- How to stop screen recording when app is terminated in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, agora.io

I developing an app using Agora iOS SDK. Here I start/stop screen sharing using RPSystemBroadcastPickerView and it works fine.

```
func prepareSystemBroadcaster() {
    if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 60, height: 60)
        let systemBroadcastPicker = RPSystemBroadcastPickerView(frame: frame)
        systemBroadcastPicker.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Agora-ScreenShare-Extension", withExtension: "appex", subdirectory: "PlugIns") {
            if let bundle = Bundle(url: url) {
                systemBroadcastPicker.preferredExtension = bundle.bundleIdentifier
            }
        }
        broadcasterPickerContainer.addSubview(systemBroadcastPicker)
    } else {
        self.showAlert(message: "Minimum support iOS version is 12.0")
    }
    
}
```

My problem is when the user terminates the app from the background if the screen is sharing. How to stop screen recording without tapping red bar?
I tried the below code in AppDelegate, but can't able to find any solution.

```
 func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {

    RPScreenRecorder.shared().stopRecording( handler: { error in
         if let error = error {
           print(error)
         }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using [`stopCapture`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpscreenrecorder/2867292-stopcapture) instead.

ReplayKit is the only way we can do screen recording with iOS due to security measures by Apple, but this also means there's limited control of it. If you still have issues, the best place for ReplayKit questions would be [apple's developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/tags/replaykit).